# server not reading data posted through curl

Tags: php, curl

This is my code

```
<?php
$url = "http://mydomain.com/coupon/process.php";
$fields = array(
                    'lname'=>"sekhar",

            );
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
 }
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);

 //execute post
 $result = curl_exec($ch);

 //close connection
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```

**process.php contains**

```
<?php 
echo "hi...".$_POST['lname'];
?>
```

$_POST is not displayed. I just get the output "hi..."

The same code was working fine in my local server. Curl is installed in both the servers. It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: check what u get in response when issue print_r($result); after $result = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: I get 1 as the result.

Comment: can you add this and try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

Comment: now I am getting nothing in return.